# Codeigniter não apresenta sua tela de Welcome

Tags: php, codeigniter, linux, ubuntu

Comecei a aprender o codeigniter alguns dias atrás e estou com o seguinte problema:

EU fiz a instalação correta do *LAMP* e do *Codeigniter* `/var/www/html/codeigniter`

Porém quando eu tento acessar a página de "*Welcome*" do *framework* usando a seguinte *url* `http://localhost/codeigniter`, o navegar simplesmente não apresenta a página *Welcome* como de costume, ele apresenta o CÓDIGO *php* de `index.php` dentro da raiz do *framework*, não consigo carregar a *view* *Welcome* do *framework*[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: veja o status do apache com `sudo service apache2 status`.

Comment: teu apache ta rodando porem sem php configurado

Comment: Você já tentou instalar esse pacote? Geralmente quando acontece esse problema o seu PHP esta instalado mas seu apache ainda precisa dessa dependência. **apt-get install libapache2-mod-php**

Answer (score 0):

O seu lamp stack não está corretamente instalado ou configurado.

Verifique se foram estes os passos que seguiu:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install apache2
```

Assumindo que vai usar mysql e que é a versão 7.2 de PHP que vai usar.

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo apt install php7.2 libapache2-mod-php7.2 php-mysql
```

Opcional caso vá usar algum destes modulos de PHP

```
sudo apt install php-curl php-json php-cgi
```

Por último fazer restart ao apache, como estás em ubuntu é simples:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Se seguiu todos estes passos, possivelmente o único passo que lhe faltará será o libapache2-mod-php7.2